# Form authentication problem with multiple IIS worker processes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm running an asp.net mvc5 application on a shared hosting environment (a2 Hosting). I ran into a problem where users get randomly un-authenticated when browsing pages WAY before session timout or expiration should be reached.

I tried playing with applicaiton pool configurations to fixed the problem and finally find out that this was related to numbers of worker processes. When the maximum number of worker processes is set to 1, no more disconnection problems.

My appliciation use real basic from authentication. The only customizing I did was usins a custom Principal object to store extra data in authentication cookie. I DON'T use Session in the application so this can't be the problem.

Comment: "I DON'T use Session in the application so this can't be the problem." I commented elsewhere on the same question you posted. Whether you explicitly use session or not, it is simply the problem, https://peterwong.net/blog/asp-net-session-and-forms-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Set it back to 1.  Why you shouldn't use web gardens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bOTesCnszo

Answer (score 0):

For enabling multiple IIS worker processes.

- Go to Services & find Asp.Net State Service Set it to Startup
  Automatic
- Open IIS Manager Goto Web Application, right click and select Explore, this will take you to the folder, find web.config file & edit this file in notepad and Change Session State to State server and Save the web.config file.
- Now edit the app pool by right clicking on it & select Advanced settings and find Maximum Worker processes & change the value & change load user profile to true. Click on OK. Open command prompt as Admin and run an "IISRESET" after complete, TEST.

This helps to boost overall application performance.